# Best practice for getters and setters for collection properties and object properties in a java class

Tags: java, properties, getter-setter

i have the following implementation

```
public class PartGroup {

   private Part iPart;

   private ArrayList<Part> iParttList;

   public Part getPart() {
      return iPart;
   }

   public void setPart( Part aPart ) {
      iPart = aPart;
   }


   public ArrayList<Part> getParttList() {
      return iParttList;
   }


   public void setParttList( ArrayList<Part> aParttList ) {
      iParttList = aParttList;
   }

}
```

Is it ok to have setters for iParttList  and iPart ?
i think it is safe to have a getter only then the consumer can use getter to get the created instance of the collection and clear or add elements to the collection
should i remove the setter and add the following implementation

```
public ArrayList<Part> getParttList() {
      if(iParttList == null)
         iParttList = new ArrayList<Part>();

      return iParttList;
   } 

public Part getPart() {
       if(iPart == null)
          iPart = new Part();

       return iPart;
   }
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: You can do how you want and how you think is better for your problem.

Comment: This question is primarly opinion based, and thus will never lead to a concise solution. Questions like yours are Off-Topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: There are no universal best practices. Things always depend on requirements. Nonetheless, the primary best practice is: don't use *neither* of them. Avoid expose internal state, and never allow outsiders to update your internal state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second implementation guards against returning null, right? So if there's a chance this object could return null (because what constructors there are permit this or it otherwise could come to pass) and that would be a Bad Thing for your intended use case, then use the second implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your original implementation seems like the standard implementation for getters and setters. Why do you think you'd need to rearrange it to the second code block?

Comment: if someone set a new ArrayList it will replace the entire list

Comment: yeah because that's what you told it to do, what is your intended functionality?

Comment: i  think it is safe to have a getter only then the consumer can use getter to get the created instance of the collection and clear of add elements to the collection, what do you think?

Comment: if you are wanting them to add parts to the parts list, you could create a separate method to allow them to do so. Additionally, if you don't want them to be able to set the full ArrayList, then remove the setter, yes.

Answer (score 0):

As we see you do not have construction to create list once you create instance of PartGroup.

I think:

1. If you have construction to create list of Part objects, and if you want to restrict consumer to change or create list via setter, then I think it is better not to have setter
2. But, if you dont have constructor to create list of Part objects, then setter is only way to create list of Part objects.

Answer (score 0):

The second implementation seems better from my point of view. It ensures that the lists aren't null under any circumstances. It also helps to reduce duplicate code that checks if the list is empty or not. Finally, calling`public void setParttList( ArrayList<Part> aParttList )` may be risky since it may set a new list even though there's one already exist.